# Enabling CORS policy for public S3 object delivered through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 object that should be publicly accessible but only from specified domains. The object is accessed through a CloudFront custom url.

I have tried the below steps:

1. Set S3 bucket permission to Public
2. Set 'Origin request policy name' = 'Managed-CORS-S3Origin behavior' in CloudFront distribution according to this [post on aws knowledge center](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error) so CloudFront passes origin
3. Added CORS policy to S3 bucket as below. "https://www.example.com" replaced with domain I want to provide access to.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

While I am able to access the object from specified domain, I am also able to access it from domains NOT specified under AllowedOrigins in the CORS policy.

Looking for some direction on how best to fix this so access is restricted to specified domains only.

Thanks!

Comment: CORS's purpose is _not_ to block anything but to relax existing restrictions enforced by browsers. Read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thanks, had a read through. Under "Examples of access control scenarios > Simple requests", doc seems to suggest you can restrict access to specific domains. This is exactly what I want to achieve! 

"If the resource owners at https://bar.other wished to restrict access to the resource to requests only from https://foo.example (i.e., no domain other than https://foo.example can access the resource in a cross-origin manner), they would send: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example" 

Looking for ways to do this with the Cloudfront / S3 setup.

Comment: That passage is poorly worded. What you should understand is that you can limit which origins you wish to allow access from in the context of a CORS handshake; but you cannot use CORS to restrict access from all user agents. CORS simply is no general substitute for server-side access control.